# ¿Cómo puedo poner un button encima de la caja de un input en html?

Tags: html, css, formularios

Tengo este formulario de registro en html y tengo un botón con un js para mostrar y ocultar contraseña. Esta comentado como  justo debajo de contraseña. La cosa es que tal y como está me sale justo debajo de la caja para escribir la contraseña y quiero que me salga encima del input de contraseña a la derecha, como sale normalmente en los forms.

Este es mi formulario:

```html
<div class="card-body px-lg-5 pt-0">
            <form class="text-center" style="color: #757575;" action="../public/forms/registro.php" method="post">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <!-- Nombre -->
                        <div class="md-form">
                            <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control" maxlength="30" required>
                            <label for="nombre">NOMBRE</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <!-- Appellidos -->
                        <div class="md-form">
                            <input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" class="form-control" maxlength="30" required>
                            <label for="apellidos">APELLIDOS</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="md-form">
                    <input type="password" id="contrasena" name="contrasena" class="form-control" aria-describedby="materialRegisterFormPasswordHelpBlock" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" maxlength="40" required>
                    <label for="contrasena">CONTRASEÑA</label>
                    <!-- botón ocultar desocultar contrasena -->
                    <i id="mostrar_contrasenaregistro" type="button" onclick="mostrarContrasenaregistro()"> <span class="fa fa-eye-slash icon"></span></i>
                </div>
                </form>
                </div>
```

Si me pudierais ayudar a ver como podría ponerlo encima. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes usar z-index. [Más información aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: Tal cual tienes el código funciona y muestra el elemento a la derecha de la palabra contraseña, entonces no se entiende bien lo que buscas lograr

Answer (score 0):

si quieres superponer un botton sobre tu input puedes usar una funcion js, que lo haga cuando este input tenga datos dentro, con un simple if podrias hacerlo, pero si lo que quieres es un icono tipo append puedes ocupar estas lineas de css

```css
i[type="button"] {
    margin-left: -50px;
    height: 20px;
    
}
```

```html
    <div class="card-body px-lg-5 pt-0">
            <form class="text-center" style="color: #757575;" action="../public/forms/registro.php" method="post">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <!-- Nombre -->
                        <div class="md-form">
                            <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control" maxlength="30" required>
                            <label for="nombre">NOMBRE</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <!-- Appellidos -->
                        <div class="md-form">
                            <input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" class="form-control" maxlength="30" required>
                            <label for="apellidos">APELLIDOS</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="md-form">
                    <input type="password" id="contrasena" name="contrasena" class="form-control" aria-describedby="materialRegisterFormPasswordHelpBlock" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" maxlength="40" required>
                    
                    <i id="mostrar_contrasenaregistro" type="button" onclick="mostrarContrasenaregistro()"> <span class="fa fa-eye-slash icon">button</span></i>
                   
                    <label for="contrasena">CONTRASEÑA</label>
                    <!-- botón ocultar desocultar contrasena -->
                    
                </div>
           </form>
       </div>
```